# Laravel: something is changing the method, what is it?

Tags: laravel, symfony, laravel-blade

I have a simple blade form mith post method and csrf token:

```
<form name="login" action="{{ route('login.do') }}" method="post" autocomplete="off">
    @csrf
    <label>
        <span class="field icon-envelope">E-mail:</span>
        <input type="email" name="email" required/>
    </label>

    <label>
        <span class="field icon-unlock-alt">Password:</span>
        <input type="password" name="password_check"/>
    </label>

    <button class="gradient gradient-orange radius icon-sign-in" type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

and the route in routes/web.php:

```
Route::post('login', 'AuthController@login')->name('login.do');
```

when I submit the form, I get the error:

> **Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException**
>
> **The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.**

As you can see, the route and the form are ok, but something is messing it up and changing the method. It won't even get to the controller layer.

some infos:

-Laravel 8.12

-I have no customized middleware

-The `htaccess` and `config/cors` are default

-The route doesn't end with a slash nor is duplicated

-Whenever I do an alteration I clean the caches

-The `APP_URL` starts with http and `SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE` is set to false due to it

-The `APP_ENV` is production

What can it be? I've read it may be something in the server that's blocking the request and changing its method, so I'm not sure if the error is laravel or server related.

Comment: Is that error message for that page? Do you maybe redirect after logging in or something?

Comment: did you try dd() your values for checking request reached your method or not.

Comment: Try once by rewrite you route like this Route::post('/update',[PersonController::class, 'update'])->name('update');

Comment: The login isn't being done. as I said, it won't even get to the controller layer.

Comment: I changed the syntax to:

Route::post('/login', [AuthController::class, 'login'])->name('login.do');

and the result was the same (yes I cleaned cache).

Comment: Please share more details - how do you submit the form? Is there any Javascript handler changing the form method?

Comment: the submition is as simples as possible. the submit button fires the form action, no JS handling anything.

Comment: Then please share the generated markup, and probably a screenshot of your developer console

Answer (score -1):

```
public function login(Request $request){
    
   dd($request->all());
    
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn form it. I would assume that the controller isn't called after all

Comment: I tried this LOCAL and got:

array:3 [▼
  "_token" => "m3F6hRrodg5307ZIJfNnZGfKvjzBrxGIQ24fWil4"
  "email" => "admin@email.com.br"
  "password_check" => "senha"
]

but when I tried it in the server, it gone straight to the error message. as I said, it won't even get to the controller layer.

Comment: please share more details of your AuthController

Comment: `code`
   public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = [
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => $request->password_check
        ];

        if(Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            return redirect()->route('admin.home');
        }

        return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrors(['Invalid email/password.']);
    }
`code`

BUT the controller isn't being called. The error happens as soon as the form is submited and application breaks into that error.

Comment: Try this, under the @csrf, add this @method('post');

Comment: I did. The outcome didn't change.

Comment: your login form, route, and login function don't have any issue. 


Route::post('login','AuthController@login')->name('login.do');

 public function login(Request $request) { 
 $credentials = [ 'email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password_check ]; 
 if( $user = \Auth::attempt($credentials)) { 
 return redirect()->route('admin.home'); 
 } 
 return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrors(['Invalid email/password.']); 
}
please check your log file

Comment: the log doens't show the error(s). isn't it strange?

I put a Log::info('construct:', $request->all()); in the construct of the AuthController and it only displays: [2020-12-14 15:01:40] production.INFO: construct:

Comment: I read somewhere that it could be the ModSec funtionality blocking the request and thus changing its verb. I turned it off and nothing changed. I'm going hopeless :'(